# How to pass UUID in the PUT request when using webtest?

Tags: python, python-requests, webtest

I am trying to test the PUT endpoint using webtest module for that. Here is what I am trying to do.

```
update_user = {'lName': 'TEST'}

live_testapp.put_json(
    '/v1/user/{uuid},',
    params=(uuid, update_user),
    headers={
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {}'.format(token),
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    status=200
)
```

I am getting following error when I try to run the test:

```
webtest.app.AppError: Bad response: 400 BAD REQUEST (not 200)
E           { "detail": "[\'da5a75c4-eabd-4d48-adeb-ff9b31b0bbce\', 
{\'lName\': \'TEST\'}] is not of type \'object\'",\n  "status": 400,\n  
"title": "Bad Request",\n  "type": "about:blank"\n}
```

Comment: `params` should be a dict just like `headers`. And the URL looks like it is missing `.format(uuid=...)`.

Comment: And the URL looks like it is missing .format(uuid=...) how do I do that? I am very new to web development. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: i think he mean `'/v1/user/{uuid}'.format(uuid=uuid)`